# Dynamically add routerLink to a component created dynamically via AJAX in Angular 5

Tags: ajax, angular, dynamic, routerlink

I've got a component that downloads data from an API. When the user clicks `Search`, the content from the API is fetched via AJAX. This content from the API is in JSON and has got an ID of the product inside. I am able to create new HTML elements based on this content and put them inside my site, but I would like every created on the fly element to have `routerLink="/detailsPage/itemID"` working, so that after clicking it would route to `detailsPage` with apropriate ID. How to do it in the most simple way? I assume some recompiling of refreshing is needed.

Comment: if you want it as a param you can do something like this: [routerLink]="['/detailsPage']" [queryParams]="{id: itemId}"

Comment: Generally `routerLink="/detailsPage/itemID` works for me with a static content. But with AJAX it doesn't work.

Comment: can you show the response you are getting from api call

Comment: API i totally fine. The question is am I just missing something or adding any `routerLink` to an element made after page loads won't work?

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this question is `HTTPClient` - Angular offers it as an easier way to use `XMLHttpRequest` (AJAX) in Angular applications, and using it also makes sure that `routerLink` or any other Angular directives will work on objects created dynamically with this method.
[Angular - HTTPClient](https://angular.io/guide/http)